# Do I need to use Promises or is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am running into an issue where I need to use the data that I get back from my Ajax code and it is grabbing the variable before it returns, so I think I have to use Promises or a callback for this.  I looked at all kinds of documentation and tutorials on Promises and it was all very confusing.  I'm just sending back a single int with one ajax call.  I think it should be very simple.

Here is my JS/JQuery:

```
$('.products').on('click', '.btnaddtocart', function (e) {
        var itemid = $(this).attr('name');
        var qty = $(this).prev('input').val();
        var qtyAvailable = $("#qty" + itemid).html();
        var qtyInCart = 0;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Shop/getItemCountInCart',
            data: { id: itemid },
            success: function (result) {
                qtyInCart = result;
                console.log("result: " + result);
            }
        });
        console.log("qty in cart: " + qtyInCart);
```

qtyInCart is always 0 and result has the number but gets output after the qtyInCart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, you just have to put `console.log("qty in cart: " + qtyInCart);` and all code using qtyInCar in the success function.

You don't need to use Promises. But, since it is an asynchronous call and you have no idea when `qtyInCart` will be assigned, you must put all code involving this variable in the `success` function.